# a copy of certificate

Tags: singular

I want to ask people to attach a copy of supporting document.

> Please attach a copy of **certificate** confirming those facts stated
> above.

Is "**certificate**" singular and does it need any articles?
I wondered because when you say "a kind/type/sort" of something, you do not add an article before the noun.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes "certificate" is singular and needs an article in this context, so it should be

> Please attach a copy of your/the certificate confirming those facts stated above.

It might be better though, to use "the" instead of "those", unless it is a reply email e.g. that is directly under the "facts" stated, then either is fine.

> Please attach a copy of your/the certificate confirming the facts stated above.

Comment: Can you please tell me the reasoning for using a singular? I came across this sentence "Please attach a copy of Certificates, Licenses, or Transcripts if you indicated 'yes' to any above."
https://www.fdl.wi.gov/fire/wp-content/uploads/sites/18/2019/03/Firefighter-Paramedic-Application-2019-ongoing.pdf

Comment: @estudent plural is being used there as it is referring to **any** certificates licenses or transcripts one may have, which can be more than 1